# Automatically organising JUnit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

On our project we organise our unit tests according to the maven convention.

```
src/main/java/com.company.project/SomeClass.java
src/test/java/com.company.project/SomeClassTest.java
```

Can anyone recommend a good tool for keeping test classes in sync when the class under test changes name or moves package, or even moves from one maven project to another?

Comment: Sounds like something that won't be available.  Perhaps an Eclipse plugin or work method may help, but how is a tool going to know when you change a class name or package without actively monitoring the file and doing a lot of work as you edit it?  Perhaps there's a tool akin to 'svn move' which you explicitly use?

Comment: In theory all the information is there to keep the two in sync.  I was thinking of implementing something myself, perhaps even using an annotation like @ClassUnderTest on each test and having a tool which can scan all the tests and update their names and packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moreUnit (http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) for eclipse.

Comment: Looks good, but only for eclipse and, as far as I can tell, it can't do a clean up of existing tests which have gone adrift, only keeps them in sync for new refactorings.  A handy plugin nonetheless.